# XML Only one root Element allowed

Tags: java, xml, dom

I get an Error within this Code while trying to add a new `Element`.

```
try {
                DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = docBuilder.parse(openFileInput(filename));
                Node task = doc.getElementsByTagName("task").item(position);
                NodeList list = task.getChildNodes();

                for(int i = 0; i<list.getLength();i++){
                    Node node = list.item(i);

                    if("task_note".equals(node.getNodeName())){
                        node.setTextContent(taskItems.get(position).get("task_note"));
                    }
                }

                Node taskNote = doc.createElement("task_image");
                taskNote.setTextContent(taskItems.get(position).get("task_image"));
                doc.appendChild(taskNote);

                TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                //DOMSource wandelt Zeichen wie < , > , & , "" automatisch in XML Sprache um
                DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(openFileOutput(filename,Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
                transformer.transform(source,result);
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException | IOException | SAXException | TransformerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Here is the Error:

```
Caused by: org.w3c.dom.DOMException: Only one root element 
        at de.appy.laluna.app.TasksList.onActivityResult(TasksList.java:161)
```

Inside the for loop, I edit the `task_note` Element. This works until I create a new `Element` after the for loop.
This leads to the error.

What is wrong and how can I solve the problem?

Kind Regards

Comment: You can only have one root element in an XML document...

Comment: Yes but where I'm declaring another root element?

Comment: Well I assume the document you start with already has a root element, and then you appended another one to the document: `doc.appendChild(taskNote);` It's kind of hard to tell though without the actual XML

Comment: Okay thank you I understand. How can I add a new child then?

Comment: Well, maybe you meant to append to the task node? `task.appendChild(taskNote)`? I'm not sure what you are wanting to do exactly.

Comment: Oh yes this is it! How could I overlooked that. THank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have 1 root element in an XML document.

It looks like you are loading an existing XML document here:

```
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(openFileInput(filename));
```

And getting an existing node from that document here:

```
Node task = doc.getElementsByTagName("KEVOX_task").item(position);
```

So, I'm assuming it has a root element already. Since you are getting an element `KEVOX_task` from that document, it's at least contained within the root element.

Later, you attempt to append to the document itself:

```
doc.appendChild(taskNote);
```

This would add more than one root element.

What you probably mean to do was add to your `task` element that you selected earlier:

```
task.appendChild(taskNote);
```